# How to set the value of REPORT_TIME_ZONE parameter?

Tags: jasper-reports

How to set the time zone of a report using the `REPORT_TIME_ZONE` built-in parameter?

Answer (score 3):

The *TimeZone* can be easily passed to the report with help of code. For example, with Java:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_TIME_ZONE, TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

In case you try to change *REPORT_TIME_ZONE* directly at *jrxml* like this:

```
<parameter name="REPORT_TIME_ZONE" class="java.util.TimeZone">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Copenhagen");]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

you will get this error:

`Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 14; Error at line 10 char 14: Duplicate declaration of parameter: REPORT_TIME_ZONE`

If you really need to set parameter at template you can use this trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TimeZone sample" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <variable name="fake" class="java.util.TimeZone">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[java.util.TimeZone.getDefault()]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put("REPORT_TIME_ZONE", java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"))]]> </initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <title>
        <band height="60">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

In this example I changed the parameter's value via parameters Map with help of fake variable:

```
$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put("REPORT_TIME_ZONE", java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"))
```

Comment: I have set the fake variable in my report. But the report data is not populated as per the time zone value set in variable.

Comment: 1) What expression are you using for showing time? 2) What version of JR are you using?

Comment: Seems like the template version doesn't work with version 7.5.0. I am using the expression `$F{fieldname}` with pattern dd.MM.yyyy for displaying the date.